# Passing XML parameters to custom views

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I am trying to implement a custom view, for which I want to be able to pass parameters via an XML layout file.  The catch is these parameters will be more or less arbitrary; they will eventually be used as parameters to construct a URL (it's not worthwhile to build and maintain a complete list of valid params).

As such, the method in ApiDemos sample code is not necessarily appropriate, given I do not know the names of the parameters.

What I have attempted to do is the following:

```
public Chart(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
    super(context, attributes);
    params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < attributes.getAttributeCount(); i++) 
        params.put(attributes.getAttributeName(i), attributes.getAttributeValue(i));
}
```

This may not be the best way to go about this.. but the main issue I have is how do I filter out android: attributes (ie. I don't want android:layout_height, etc. to be in params)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this by using an overloaded version of getAttributeValue().  Still open for input if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Actually, I may need a better solution.  It doesn't appear I can use styles if I do things this way..